# "Crop" excel sheet to working area in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

So, I have a pretty good thing going with pandas where I take in a dictionary, convert that dictionary to a dataframe, and write that dataframe to a sheet. Something like:

```
import pandas

some_array_of_dicts = [{"Name": "Roman", "Location": "Tagbilaran"}, {"Name": "Joy", "Location": "California"}]
writer = pandas.ExcelWriter("some sheet.xlsx", engine="openpyxl")
some_data_frame = pandas.DataFrame(some_array_of_dicts)
some_data_frame.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="some sheet")
writer.save()
writer.close()
```

But the outputted excel file often has many more blank columns and rows that I didn't originally put there.

[image: Way too much whitespace]

Is there anyway to "crop" out these blank rows and columns when or after I write to the excel? To be clear, this is not a problem with the data frame:

```
print(some_data_frame)

   Name    Location
0  Roman  Tagbilaran
1    Joy  California
```

Comment: Can you add some data sample, [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Significantly changed. Is it better now?

Answer (score -1):

Try using the [pandas.DataFrame.dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html).

For example:

```
pandas.DataFrame(some_array_of_dicts).dropna().to_excel(writer, sheet_name="some sheet")
```

The above should remove all empty rows.

For more details, you can see the following link:
https://hackersandslackers.com/pandas-dataframe-drop/